# Using exponential integral function for raster calculation in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

How do I use "exponential integral" function for raster calculation in ArcPy?

The equation that I want to apply in raster calculator is of the form `EXPINT (r^2*S/(4*T*t))`. Here, `r`, `S`, and `t` are constant parameters and I have raster file (say `raster1` ) for `T` parameter.

I am a beginner.

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
from scipy import special as sp
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

raster1 = ("D:/raster1")
raster2 = ("D:/raster2")
raster3 = (raster1 * raster2 * 30 * 4 * np.pi)/-sp.expi(- (0.20 ** 2 * 0.0001/(4 * raster1 * 30)))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** ESRI's [Spatial Analysis Map Algebra](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/spatial-analyst/mapalgebra/what-is-map-algebra.htm) contains a fixed set of operators which can manipulate rasters. Your desired EXPINT() function is not among them.

**Longer Answer:** Since you want to calculate this value for every cell in a new raster based on constants and the value of a corresponding cell in an existing raster, a new feature called the `Raster Cell Iterator` (RCI) will (maybe) be able to help solve this problem.

Essentially, it is an iterator to access one cell at a time for every row/column in a given raster; [read about it here](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/spatial-analyst/analytics/introducing-the-raster-cell-iterator/).

[You can see python code to iterate and compute individual cells in this example blog post.](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/spatial-analyst/analytics/unleash-the-power-of-rastercelliterator-to-perform-custom-raster-analysis/)

**What you will be doing is something like this:**

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
from scipy import special as sp
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

for [r,c] in raster3:
    raster3[r,c] =  (raster1[r,c] * raster2[r,c] * 30 * 4 * np.pi)/-sp.expi(- (0.20 ** 2 * 0.0001/(4 * raster1[r,c] * 30)))

raster3.save()
```